# how to use conditional sum linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

What is wrong here? How to filter out negative elements correctly?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         int[] array = { 1, 2, -3, 4, 5, -1, 4, -2 };

         double sumOfElem = array.Sum(element => element < 0);
         Console.WriteLine(sumOfElem);
    }
}
```

Comment: You tell us - what *is* wrong here? (Yes, we can guess in this case, but please provide details on what your problem is, what you want to achieve and why what you're using isn't working)

Comment: the lambda in Sum is a selector, not a filter.

Comment: The lack of a clear question.

Comment: You need to at least specify what the desired outcome of the program is....

Comment: You can always select what you want to sum: `var negatives=array.Where(i => i < 0); int sum=negatives.Sum();`. Due to the deferred execution of `Where` that doesn't "cost" more. But it increases readability, testability and maintainability.

Answer (score 14):

I think you need this:

```
double sumOfElem = array.Sum(element => (element < 0 ? 0 : element));
```

This way you are using an overload of `Sum` that utilises a transform function (so called *selector*), that is applied to each element of the array.

The above filters out *negative* elements. If you want to filter out *positive* ones, then simply inverse the comparison operator:

```
double sumOfElem = array.Sum(element => (element > 0 ? 0 : element));
```

Answer (score 9):

You could try this one:

```
int sumOfElem = array.Where(element => element < 0)
                     .Sum();
```

You can't filter your values inside the `Sum`. You should first filter the values and then sum them.

**Update**

Saying that *You can't filter your values inside the* `Sum`, I mean you can't pass a predicate in the `Sum` method.

Comment: Not strictly true, you could do `double sumOfElem = array.Sum(element => Math.Min(0, element));`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis You are correct. That I was trying to say is that we can't pass a predicate in the `Sum`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Oops, I overlooked this. Thank you very much !