# How do you find the positive sum of an array that also has negative numbers?

Tags: c#

```
public static int PositiveSum(int[] arr)
{   
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i > arr.Length; i++)
  {
    sum+=arr[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Example:

```
[1,-4,7,12] => 1 + 7 + 12 = 20
```

Note: if there is nothing to `sum`, the `sum` defaults to 0.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.Please take time out for a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com//tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com//help). You might also want to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com//questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Should really be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542631/how-to-use-conditional-sum-linq-c-sharp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use conditional sum linq c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542631/how-to-use-conditional-sum-linq-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, with minimum changes to your code, is to add a condition inside the `for` loop that sums the values allowing only positive numbers to be added.

Something you must change is the condition in the loop,  `i > arr.Length` will break the cycle immediately, even if `Length` is 0, it needs to be `i < arr.Length`.

```
public static int PositiveSum(int[] arr)
{
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
  {
    if (arr[i] > 0)
      sum += arr[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: So I took this and flipped around the greater than sign and it work! Thanks for the help! Im new to coding so these things are pretty tricky to me! Thank you for your help my friend!

Comment: @DeanBoilek, I'm glad I could help, a good way to thank me would be to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/684852).

Answer (score 1):

I would try filtering the `arr` to only contain positive numbers, then use sum on that new list:

```
public static int PositiveSum(int[] arr)
{
        var pos = arr.Where(x => x > 0);
        int sum = pos.Sum();
        return sum;
}
```